# JavaFX extending PropertyValueFactory

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a TableView of Objects which contain Ids that are mapped to other objects of other types. I need a TableColumn which, instead of showing an id, shows the object mapped to the id. I thought I could maybe do this by creating my own PropertyValueFactory, like so:

```
public class SomePropertyValueFactory extends PropertyValueFactory<SomeObject, String> {

    public SomePropertyValueFactory(String property) {
        super(property);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<SomeObject, String> parameter) {
        SomeOtherObject obj = function(parameter.getValue().getId());
        return obj.toString();
    }

}
```

Is this a viable solution? Will it function properly? I've tried this but a LoadException was thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: ui.view.SomePropertyValueFactory
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ui.view.SomePropertyValueFactory.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: And you can't do this with a custom CellRenderer?

Comment: Would that be a more suitable solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending a class to be used by FXML, it must either has a no-argument constructor, or (in JavaFX 8) it must have a constructor whose parameters are annotated `@NamedArg`. So you could do

```
public class SomePropertyFactory ... {

    public SomePropertyFactory(@NamedArg("property") String property) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Additionally, the code you posted won't compile since the return value of the `call` method is a `String`, where it should be an `ObservableValue<String>`.

However, I don't really see the point in making this a subclass of `PropertyValueFactory` at all. Why not just implement `Callback` directly? The only use for this class is in `setCellValueFactory(...)` and the parameter type there is `Callback`. And you don't seem to be inheriting anything at all from your superclass.

Comment: The reason for extending the PropertyValueFactory class is for the simple reason it's more simple to have: PropertyValueFactory<S, T> rather than Callback<CellDataFeatures<S,T>, ObservableValue<T>>

Comment: How is it more simple than implementing the base interface? You're overriding the only method anyway.

Comment: I also wanted the class to be defined as a PropertyValueFactory and only used in this situation, setCellValueFactory(...)

Comment: Also I, in a rushed manner, wrote the code in the text editor which is why i made the mistake.